window.Resumed method not working in .net maui
I want to perform following senario :
When i goto sleep mode and resume to application. i want to call method i tired following code but its not working any solution?
protected override Window CreateWindow(IActivationState activationState)
    {
        var window = base.CreateWindow(activationState);
        window.MinimumHeight = PhotoScannerConstants.WINDOW_HEIGHT;
        window.MinimumWidth = PhotoScannerConstants.WINDOW_WIDTH;        
        window.Activated  += OnActivated;
        window.Resumed += Resumed; 

        return window;
    }
   

OnActivated and Resumed method created.

What does "not working" mean?  Is it crashing or giving you an error or exception?  Where are you trying to call this code from?

this event not performed

On which platform do you want to run the maui project? Do you call the call the ConfigureLifecycleEvents method on the MauiAppBuilder object in the CreateMauiapp method of your MauiProgram class?

Platform lifecycle events indicates that different platforms have different methods for using Windows.Resume. Which platform are you trying to implement this method on? Also, did you call ConfigureLifecycleEvents in your code ?
